# MERN - Express not receiving data from Post request

Tags: node.js, express, backend, mern

I am trying to send data from a search bar into my backend express server. However for some reason, it's not being updated.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';


const StockSearchBar = () => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("Stock or Crypto Symbol");

  const handleSearch = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }


  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log({search})

    if (setSearch !== '') {
      const searchResult = {search};

      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type':  'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(searchResult)
      };
  
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/search', options)
      .then(
        () => {
          console.log("Search entered");
        }
      );


      // console.log(searchResult);
    }

  };
  
  return (
      
      <>
    <div className="searchBar">
      <label>Look for other Stocks or Cryptos: </label>
      <input  type='text' onChange={handleSearch} placeholder={search}/>
      <Button variant="success" type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>Success</Button>
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default StockSearchBar;
```

and here's the backend code

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const fs = require("fs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const Stock = require("./model/Stock");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cron = require('node-cron');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//MIDDLEWARE
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb' }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('backend'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

// DATABASE

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Stock.find({}).then(
        items => res.json(items)
    ).catch(err => console.log(err))
});

app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
        search: req.body,
    });
});

app.post("/search", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
        search: req.body,
    });
});

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log("Server is running...");
});
```

In the front end - after clicking a button it console logs an object with the search entered.
However on the backend, all I get is json text like so:

```
{
"search": {}
}
```

It doesnt get updated even though the server is continually running. Thoughts?

Comment: What does your `search` object look like before it's sent? can you give us an example of the format?

Comment: Hey Dylan, I'll be honest with you - I think I'm simply going to just learn basics of express. Because I copied some youtube tutorials and hoped it would work but I'm stuck. I gave you a thumbs up, but if you really wanna help me it might not be the easiest thing do solve. Anyways, my search object is completely empty. I'm using a searchbar to change its state which originally is useState("Stock or Crypto Symbol"); . Then on click I am trying to set a new state (of whatever was typed in) to be sent to the backend to the '/search' directory which I created using app.get('/search').

Comment: I think the problem is in the index.js node file. I have an '/' directory which I display some other content to. And then I simply tried to add another directory using app.get("/search") - it was originally app.post("/search") but I kept getting an error saying cannot get /search so I added it, while keeping app.post("/search"). I gave them the same functions res.json({ search: req.body }); because I really don't know what to put.. the result is an empty search: {} - it seems to be ignorinig the req.body request. I'm pretty sure the mistake is somewhere around the app.get & app.post